# Show Karma Instanbul code coverage on browser

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

I'm trying to launch the code coverage result generated by Istambul in the same browser as Karma test results.

I see that Karma or Istambul is generating a folder named `coverage` (when running `--codeCoverage`) which contains an HTML page containing all coverage results, but I have to open it manually. Is it possible that this page is opened in a similar way to the test results from Karma?

I could always open the index.html directly `open coverage.html`, but I'm looking for a more official way if there is one. Ideally on the same page as the test results.

> I've looked all over the place but could not find any way of accomplishing it without 3rd party tools.

This is the Karma test results, I would like the coverage to be opened here as well.
[image: Karma test result preview]

**Project info**
ng-cli: `8.3.23`
Angular: `8.2.14`
Karma: `4.1.0`

Comment: Can't you just have a script that runs `"open path/to/coverage/index.html"`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, that was my initial thought but wanted to see if karma has something native for this. I will specify it in the post.

Comment: Don't think Karma internally supports this. It can only show the pass/failed test results

Comment: @Mohit I imagined as I couldn't find any reference online, but was hoping maybe somebody has a workaround

Comment: It doesn't, no.

Comment: I wondered for it too long time back when I was using Karma, but couldn't found a way. Instead we did it via script, like opening these 'lcov' coverage files to show the coverage.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will research a bit more and if not I will go for that solution.

Comment: @Mohit do you do it in a normal browser or in the instance Karma launches?

Comment: I would prefer do it in a normal browser rather than Karma instance. Because it might cause crashing issues that's normal with Karma :)

Comment: Nice to know, thanks! I will open in a separate browser then.